# __builtin_trap: when to use it?

Tags: c++, gcc, built-in

gcc provides additional builtin functions "for optimization".

One of them is `void __builtin_trap (void)` which essentially is here to abort the program by executing an illegal command.

From the doc:

> __builtin_trap function causes the program to exit abnormally. GCC implements this
>   function by using a target-dependent mechanism (such as intentionally
>   executing an illegal instruction) or by calling abort. The mechanism
>   used may vary from release to release so you should not rely on any
>   particular implementation.

Why would you ever use this rather than `exit(1)` or `abort`? Why did the gcc developers see this as an optimization function?

Comment: Maybe for easy post-mortem debugging?

Comment: If I was building a system with high uptime requirements, in stress testing calling __builtin_trap() at random intervals would be a brutal and effective way to test a supervisor - multiple worker process model.

Comment: You mean rather than `abort()`?

Comment: Yes, exit(1) or abort would be alternatives.

Comment: If I were to implement C++ exceptions (or something similar) and I wanted the C++11 optimization that uncaught exceptions lead to immediate termination, possibly without cleanup ( https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept/ "violation of `noexcept` specification now would result in calling `std::terminate` and the program would have the freedom to not unwind the stack. ... This guarantees that the exception will not get out of `noexcept` function ... while still allowing compiler no-throw optimizations."), I would use `__builtin_trap()` to allow those "no-throw optimizations."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `exit(1)` causes the program to terminate normally with an error status code. See [the cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit). In contrast `__builtin_trap` causes the program to terminate abnormally.

The simplest way to see the differences is to look at the guarantees made by `exit`, if doing one of those things is something you don't want to happen, `__builtin_trap` would be better.

Debugging is the most common example, as `__builtin_trap` could trigger a debugger to dump the process, while `exit` would not (since the program terminates "normally" with an error).

Comment: `abort` would be a more portable way in regular of killing the process immediately due to a bug; `__builtin_trap`, I suspect, is there because `abort` is a library function and GCC can't always count on linking on the standard library.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo this leads to another question: how would you implement `abort`?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot glibc on Linux implements it by removing all signal handlers and then sending the process a `SIGTRAP` signal, which terminates the process (though debuggers usually break instead). It also afterwards sends itself `SIGKILL`, then infinite loops, just in case. I imagine that `__builtin_trap` instead uses a trap instruction, where available.

Answer (score 6):

The `__builtin` functions are not necessarily for optimisation - they are for "doing things that the compiler can't do directly from source code", including support for "special instructions" and "architecture-specific operations". One of the main purposes of `__builtin` functions is that the compiler will "know" what these do at a later stage. Although there are "library optimisations" in the compiler, the compiler can use `__builtin` functions much more freely to determine that the behaviour is something specific - for example, `__builtin_trap` can be relied upon to "not continue to the next instruction", so the compiler doesn't have to worry about code like:

```
if (x <= 0.0) __builtin_trap();
y = ln(x);
```

It can then make use of the "fast inline version of `ln`", since the error has been caught already.

Note also that `__builtin_trap` is almost guaranteed to end up as a "stop" in the debugger, where `exit(1)` or some such will just exit the program with a "not success" result code, which is rather annoying if you are trying to figure out where that math error message came from...

Comment: You could trap the signal (`SIGILL` usually) that `__builtin_trap()` generates and continue execution. For example, a debugger could do that. So in general, it can't be assumed that `x > 0.0` after the trap.

Comment: I guarantee that the compiler WILL assume that `__builtin_trap` won't continue - yes, you can trap it, and you can continue, but since the compiler doesn't expect it, you get what you deserve, and it will still assume `x > 0.0`. The `__builtin_trap` is how a compiler knows you're using for example `assert`.