# generating trap/segfault messages in dmesg

Tags: c, linux

I had a program that was segfaulting.

When I went to investigate and ran dmesg  I could see lines like this:

```
[955.915050]  traps: foo_bar[123] general protection ip:7f5fcc2d4306 sp:7ffd9e5868b8 ...
```

Now the program has been fixed and I'm trying to write some analysis scripts across different systems to find similar messages and was hoping to induce a line in the dmesg log to get a baseline for what to look for and see if there's a difference between, say, a sigbus(10) and a sigill(4)

I tried to do it via `kill -11` on the command line . No entry in dmesg

I tried to do it via `signal(getpid(), 11)` in the code. No entry in dmesg

I tried to do it via `signal 11` after attaching in gdb . No entry in dmesg

I tried to do it via writing bad code and it worked for SEGV, but I can't figure out how to trigger a SIGBUS (for example)

I'm guessing that there is more than one path for handling the signal depending on how it occurs and my attempts above just aren't doing it the right way.

How can I trigger/send a signal to my program that'll get a line in dmesg? Is there some kernel or log configuration I can twiddle to get those lines?

Update:

" [__builtin_trap: when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734759/builtin-trap-when-to-use-it?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) " shows how to get a SIGILL but alas doesn't have a signal-agnostic solution)

Comment: If you have systemd in your OS you can use `coredumpctl` to list all coredumped programs. Your segfaulting program should be in that list. If your goal is to monitor your program crashes you can use `coredumpctl`, I guess.